# Learning a stochastic pattern in a count TS using DeepAR

Tags: time-series, forecasting, negative-binomial-distribution, lstm

I am trying to the learn the following pattern of count time series of vehicle demand every hour.

[image]

The count time series is generated from a negative binomial distribution with parameters n = 9 and p = 0.5 every 4 hours. The interval in-between has magnitude = 0.

I would like to know if I can use this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.04110?context=stat.ML), Deep Autoregressive recurrent neural network to learn this :

Please see the code below:

https://github.com/JosePeeterson/demand_prediction

simply run main.py to test Deep autoregression. In the test output I can see that the period of 4 hours is not being learnt as well as correct mean prediction output at each time step.

Is there any count time series data that is known to work with this code?

Comment: What do you mean by "parameters n = 9 and p = 0.5 every 4 hours"? Is your data in buckets of length 4 hours? If so, what should the DeepAR learn, since your predictions will then again be for 4-hour-buckets?

Comment: every 4 hours I sample from a nbinom(9,0.5) the 3 hours in-between is all zeros. The DeepAR should learn the temporal dependencies i.e. period of the spikes as well as the the distribution from which this spike comes from. The prediction can be for the next time step. It should not learn absolute positions but given a window of say 20 time steps it should predict the value of the 21st step as sample from nbinom distribution if it happens to be the 4th step after 3 zeros or zero if it is in-between spikes.

Comment: Ah. Why do you do that? And why do you want the DeepAR to learn that piece of information? If you *know* something, it's always much better to pre- and postprocess data, rather than giving your system a lot of rope and hope it doesn't hang itself with it.

Comment: In the real data there will be many periods and each one will come from a different parameter distrubiton so this information is not known apriori. we just know that the demand comes from a negative binomial distribuion.

Comment: So you won't know that there is a (potentially) nonzero data point only every four periods, and periods 1-3 out of every four will be zero? If so, why do you test DeepAR with synthetic data that does exhibit this regularity? If your real data does not exhibit this, then it's not relevant DeepAR does not detect it, is it? Also, how do you **know** real demand is negbin? Typically, a distribution could be a good *description* of data, but data truly does not really follow a distribution.

Comment: The ACF plot of my count time series data has significant peaks for 24, 36,48, 168 hours. I want to capture this regularity. I wish to have the DeepAR to learn 168 distributions which then be used for predictions within any 168 steps. Does it make sense? For the distribution let's just assume the data comes from there as a starting point.

Comment: OK. From what I know of DeepAR, it should definitely be able to capture such multiple seasonalities, given enough data, which it sounds you have. [Of course the forecasts will vary less than the observations](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5567/1352), but have you looked at [seasonplots](https://otexts.com/fpp3/seasonal-plots.html) of DeepAR's forecasts with these seasonalities, to see whether the forecasts at least show *some* seasonal patterns?

Comment: Thanks for your inputs @StephanKolassa I shall take a look.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to capture this pattern using pytorch DeepAR for two nbinom values (n=9,p=0.5) and (n=4,p=0.75) with period of 8 hours for each. The two signals are interleaved like below.
[image]

Run My_demo.ipynb to see the prediction of means of the two frequencies in the following repo.

https://github.com/JosePeeterson/2_freq_nbinom_LSTM/tree/master